# Select Combination of columns from Table A not in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two sets of table with all the contacts on an Account their titles and etc. For data migration purposes I need to select All ContactsIds with their AccountID  from Table A that do not exist in TableB. Its the combination of both the ContactId and the AccountID. I have tried the following:

```
Select * from Final_Combined_Result wfcr 

 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select Contact_ID, Account_ID from Temp_WFCR)
```

I know this is completely off, but I have looked at a couple of other questions on here but was unable to find an appropriate solution.

I have also tried this:

```
Select * from Final_Combined_Result wfcr  
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (Select Contact_ID, Account_ID from Temp_WFCR as tc 
   where tc.Account_ID=wfcr.Account_InternalID 
   AND tc.Account_ID=wfcr.Contact_InternalID)
```

This seems to be correct but I would like to make sure.

Comment: Are you looking to output different columns? or restrict the number of rows to only those that dont have contact and account ids?

Comment: You need to correlate those somehow. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Your latest edit looks good except for the sub select where you are joining to `account_id` twice.  Change the second one to `contact`.  This is the essentially the same as the one I originally posted.  Check my most recent edit and let me know if you need any more help/examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@juergend's answer shows the left join.

Using a not exists you join in the subselect, it would look like this:

```
Select wfcr.*
from 
  Final_Combined_Result wfcr 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (Select 1 --select values dont matter here, only the join restricts.
     from 
       Temp_WFCR t
     where t.Contact_ID = wfcr.Contact_InternalID
       and t.account_id = wfcr.Account_InternalID 
     )
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Select wfcr.ContactsId, wfcr.AccountID
from Final_Combined_Result wfcr 
left join Temp_WFCR t_wfcr ON t_wfcr.ContactsIds = wfcr.ContactsId 
                          AND t_wfcr.AccountID = wfcr.AccountID
WHERE t_wfcr.AccountID is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)